# Honda vfr 800 vtec 2011

Tags: honda, motorcycle, torque-specification, handlebars

I have just put new risers on my Honda VFR800 and upgraded the pinch bolt for the clip on bars to tritium .

Question:

Do I need to use thread lock?

What torque setting should I use?

Comment: What is the bolt?  M5, m6?   If you give the bolt diameter and thread pitch we can tell you the torque value.

Answer (score 1):

Titanium M5 metric bolts have a torque specification of 25 inch pounds.

Yes, you should use thread lock for all handlebar related bolts that are related to your safety as a rider.  You can use the lowest level of thread lock.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed an aftermarket handlebar accessory, the manufacturer should list torque specification. Otherwise, you will need to consult the manual.

I recommend using anti-seize on the bolts, not thread locker. Regularly inspect the bolts for any sign of backing out or movement.